# PySide2 , button doesn't get setStyleSheets

Tags: python, maya, pyside2

Was trying to get some basics of PySide2 inside Maya and right now I am facing problem, that button doesn't get `translateButtonX.setStyleSheet(...)` which I want, it just ignores it. I tried to debug it and noticed that , if I set `window.setStyleSheet(...)` not from image, from color rgb for example , then everything works. Anybody knows what am I missing ?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui

try:
    from shiboken import wrapInstance
except:
    from shiboken2 import wrapInstance


def getMayaWindow():
    pointer = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if pointer is not None:
        return wrapInstance(long(pointer), QWidget)

######################################################################
def constraintMaster_UI():
    objectName = 'PyConstraintMasterWin'
    #check if ui already exists or not
    if cmds.window('PyConstraintMasterWin', exists=1):
        cmds.deleteUI('PyConstraintMasterWin',wnd=1)

    #create window#

    parent = getMayaWindow()
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(parent)
    window.setObjectName(objectName)
    window.setWindowTitle('Constraint Master')

    #create main widget#

    mainWidget = QWidget()
    window.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
    QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Windows')

    #Create main vertical layout#

    verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(mainWidget)
    imagePath = cmds.internalVar(upd=1) + 'icons/test.png'
    window.setStyleSheet('background-image:url(' + imagePath + 
    ');border:solid black 1px;')

    #create the translate layout#

    translateLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    verticalLayout.addLayout(translateLayout)

    #create translate label#

    translateLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Translate:')
    translateLayout.addWidget(translateLabel)

    translateButtonX = QtWidgets.QPushButton('X')
    translateLayout.addWidget(translateButtonX)
    translateButtonX.setStyleSheet('background-color:rgb(0, 210, 
    255);border:white 1px;')


    #show the window
    window.show()

constraintMaster_UI()
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Tried a minimal example and both the *color* and the *image* works.
Maybe since it's a Maya plugin, the path of the image does not exist, try getting the absolute path so you are certain:

```
imagePath = os.path.abspath(cmds.internalVar(upd=1) + 'icons/test.png')
```

then you will not care if the plugin gets executed from a different directory.